# Conseguir varios valores en una consulta

Tags: sql, python, python-2.7

Tengo este código:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT nom FROM productes WHERE listacompra = 1')
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in rows:
  print(row[0])
```

En la base de datos SQL, tengo dos filas con algo como esto:

id 1, nom Natillas, listacompra 1

id 2, nom Chocolate, listacompra 1

Lo que quiero conseguir es exactamente lo que me muestra el código anterior pero simplemente almacenado en una variable (como diccionarios) o en varias. Teniendo en cuenta que no sabemos cuántas filas hay con listacompra = 1.

Muchas gracias

Comment: dentro del for asigna el valor a un arreglo por ejemplo listaX.append(row[0]), no se si sea lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que recibes de un `cursor.fetchall()` es una lista de tuplas, por lo que has indicado en los comentarios, algo así: `[(u'Natillas',), (u'Chocolate',)]`. Es decir tuplas de un único elemento, lógicamente, por que el `select` solo lista una sola columna. Para transformar esta salida en una lista "plana", puedes usar comprensión de listas de la siguiente forma:

```
rows = [(u'Natillas',), (u'Chocolate',)]
nombres = [row[0] for row in rows]
print(nombres)

> ['Natillas', 'Chocolate']
```

Básicamente lo que estamos haciendo es extraer el primer elemento de cada tupla `row[0]` y quedarnos solo con él. Una dato importante, hacer esto solo tiene sentido cuando simplemente quieres quedarte o tienes una única columna, si tuvieras más la estructura de lista de tuplas sería lo más apropiado.

Answer (score 0):

Dado el código que publicas, no tienes que hacer nada especial, de hecho, ya tienes los resultados almacenados en la variable `rows`, que luego recorres para imprimir cada fila.

Si no quieres que imprima, simplemente deja de recorrer la lista y haz otra cosa con ella.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT nom FROM productes WHERE listacompra = 1')
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  #listo, los resultados están en la variable rows.
```

Comment: El problema es que al hacer eso y después "print rows" me devuelve "[(u'Natillas',), (u'Chocolate',)]". Sölo quiero que aparezca la palabra "Natillas" y la palabra "Chocolate" en variables independientes o en su defecto ["Natillas", "Chocolate"] en una única variable.